# How do I compute the 4-component efficiency vector for an Nx4 Mueller Matrix where N > 4?

Tags: optics, computational-physics, polarization, linear-algebra, software

I am trying to use [this paper](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1999ASPC..184....3C) by Manuel Collados to better understand polarization analysis to determine the efficiency of generalized Mueller Matrices. Equation #8 (on page 5 of the paper) works only for determining efficiency for MxM square Mueller Matrices (ex: 4x4). If the number of dimensions of the matrix exceed 4, then my method will not work. To account for larger values of M, I need to use SVD to determine the optimal demodulization matrix for a given Mueller Matrix.

How can I apply these techniques for non-square Mueller Matrices of dimension Nx4 where N > 4?

I am looking to improve my understanding rather than simply fix my python code, which is as follows:

```
import numpy as np

def svd_eff(mueller_mat,n):
    demod_mat = np.linalg.svd(mueller_mat)[0] # docs --> https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html
    eff = [] # efficiency
    temp = []
    for i in range(len(demod_mat)):    # First for loop selects the row
        for j in range(len(demod_mat[i])):    # For that row selected by the ith iteration of the first loop, do work with the row
            temp.append(demod_mat[i][j] ** 2)    # Apply the math to each element (j) of the ith row and append them to the temporary list
        eff.append((n * (sum(temp))) ** (-.5))    # For the ith row, append the sum of temp to the efficiency list
        temp = []    # Finish by clearing the values for temp so it can be ready for the next iteration of i, and the next set of j columns.
    return(eff)

def p_tot(eff):
    p = ((eff[1] ** 2) + (eff[2] ** 2) + (eff[3] ** 2)) ** (.5)
    return(p)
```

Then I tested to check if the ASP Mueller Matrix works properly.

```
# Test for ASP
asp = [[1 , 0.77 , 0.41 , -0.36] ,
        [1 , -0.06 , 0.41 , -0.86] ,
        [1 , -0.06 , -0.41 , -0.86] ,
        [1 , 0.77 , -0.41 , - 0.86] ,
        [1 , 0.77 , 0.41 , 0.36] ,
        [1 , -0.06 , 0.41 , 0.86] ,
        [1 , -0.06 , -0.41 , 0.86] ,
        [1 , 0.77 , -0.41 , 0.36]]
demod_asp_mat = np.linalg.svd(asp)[0]
e = svd_eff(asp,8)
```

Then I print to check the results.

```
# Demodulation Matrix
print(demod_asp_mat)
>>

[[-0.41174495 -0.099828    0.39390378 -0.25001071 -0.59995678 -0.2776586
  -0.07744517 -0.39974334]
 [-0.32602433 -0.34285109  0.36784976  0.47850776  0.0459349  -0.24435688
   0.2472335   0.53752528]
 [-0.32684319 -0.37353722 -0.33861625  0.4162461   0.19778451 -0.01441933
  -0.55547917 -0.34327533]
 [-0.43183775 -0.37646522 -0.28223326 -0.28354071  0.01046844  0.52869612
   0.4802812  -0.03794648]
 [-0.38399047  0.25434159  0.35023007 -0.2913843   0.73531287 -0.11644569
  -0.01266459 -0.16090603]
 [-0.25972197  0.50322069  0.26351812  0.37967084 -0.181291    0.63846118
  -0.15712374  0.02312409]
 [-0.26054083  0.47253456 -0.44294789  0.31740918 -0.06242841 -0.37968497
   0.46536941 -0.21737404]
 [-0.38480933  0.22365546 -0.35623594 -0.35364596 -0.14582454 -0.13459183
  -0.39017144  0.59859585]]

# Efficiency
print(e)
>>
[0.35355339059327379, 0.35355339059327379, 0.35355339059327373, 0.35355339059327368, 0.35355339059327379, 0.35355339059327373, 0.35355339059327368, 0.35355339059327373]
```

The problem is that I have 8 *identical* efficiencies, but I only need 4. The numpy SVD has three returns but I'm not sure which to use. What is my mistake? I think I should use the [pseudo-inverse](http://www.sci.utah.edu/~gerig/CS6640-F2012/Materials/pseudoinverse-cis61009sl10.pdf), but I'll have the same problem if it's not a 4x4 matrix.

Comment: Would [scicomp.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Perhaps. While the code gives the solution I need, I was hoping to see the math behind why my original approach was unsuccessful. I was not sure if that was a more appropriate place. If it is, feel free to have it moved.